# Is it possible to have application test errors highlighted in the editor with Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, xcode4

When I run logic tests with Xcode 4 and failures occur, the test failures are listed in the issue navigator and the lines of code where the failures occur are highlighted in the editor.

For example, with this logic test:

```
- (void)testExample
{
    STFail(@"Unit tests are not implemented yet in TinyWordsLogicTests");
}
```

The line with STFail is highlighted as an error in the editor, with the error message "Unit tests are not implemented yet in TinyWordsLogicTests" appearing to the right of the line of code.

When I create a similar test with an STFail call in my application testing target and run the application tests on my device, the output of the test shows that it failed, but no error is listed in the issue navigator and the line of code with the failure is not highlighted.

Is it possible to achieve the same level of error reporting in the IDE with application tests as is possible with logic tests?

Comment: Assuming these tests were in place before Xcode 4, did you convert them to do things the way Xcode 4 likes? Namely, have you created a new template project with "Include unit tests" to see how it's set up?