# Is there a keyboard shortcut to maximize/minimize the output window in Xcode 4?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, unit-testing, xcode4

I'm currently trying to workaround some apparent shortcomings of cocoa touch application tests in Xcode 4 (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624466/is-it-possible-to-have-application-test-errors-highlighted-in-the-editor-with-xco)). Since failures of application tests are not highlighted in the editor window like failures of logic tests, I find myself using the mouse to scroll through the output window to see the results of failed tests.

I would prefer to use keyboard commands if possible to quickly look at the results of the tests and then quickly move back to the editor. Are there some keyboard shortcuts in Xcode 4 for maximizing and minimizing the output window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Command+Shift+Y` opens and closes the debug area, but I don't know of a keyboard shortcut to maximize it.

Here's a [nice cheat sheet](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html) you can print out with lots of keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks! Not quite what I was looking for, but by sizing the debug area to a larger size and then using Command+Shift+Y to toggle it on/off, I can achieve almost the effect I was looking for.

Comment: ...brilliant, Greg!  A helpful productivity tool that just made my day

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a direct shortcut, but along with Jose Ibanez shortcut, here are some relevant ones.

- `Cmd+0` Toggle left pane
- `Cmd+Alt+0` Toggle right pane
- `Cmd+Shift+Y` Toggle bottom pane